# using regexp substitution part in postgres string functions

Tags: postgresql, regular-expression

I hit this question trying to answer [one in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106960/using-lpad-in-regexp-replace). When I pass `\1` as first argument to `lpad(string text, length int [, fill text])` function, it looks like it interprets `\1` as *regexp substitution part* looking for string to pad chars, but then interprets same `\1` as *text* (it is literally - '\1') calculating its length to substract from second argument: `lpad('aaa',5,'b')` calculates `5-length('\1')`, not `5-length('aaa')`.

**So the question is - are we meant to use SQL string functions with regexp substitution part meta syntax? What are the restrictions?**
Eg: [concat, format, repeat, substr understand it, while length, initcap, ascii](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) interpret it as just text.

Now I see that length, initcap, ascii accept **string** as argument, while format, repeat accept **text**, but then `ltrim(text...` and `lpad(text...` seem to be mix - they "understand" regexp metasyntax to find position and then fail to "convert string to text" to count input length?..

Here an example:

```
t=# with a as (select 'a 2 b'::text s)
t-# select
t-#   regexp_replace(s,' (\d){1} ','')
t-# , regexp_replace(s,' (\d){1} ','\1') _regular
t-# , regexp_replace(s,' (\d){1} ',concat('.','\1','.')) concat_regular
t-# , regexp_replace(s,' (\d){1} ',length('.\1')::text) length_string
t-# , regexp_replace(s,' (\d){1} ',reverse('\1')) reverse_string
t-# , regexp_replace(s,' (\d){1} ',initcap('\1')) initcap_broken
t-# , initcap(regexp_replace(s,' (\d){1} ','\1')) initcap_orig
t-# , regexp_replace(s,' (\d){1} ',ltrim('\1','a')) ltrim_broken
t-# , regexp_replace(s,' (\d){1} ',lpad('\1',5,'.')) lpad_broken
t-# , regexp_replace(s,' (\d){1} ',ascii('\1')::text) ascii_broken
t-# , regexp_replace(s,' (\d){1} ',format('\1')::text) format_regular
t-# , regexp_replace(s,' (\d){1} ',repeat('\1',3)) repeat_regular
t-# from a
t-# ;
 regexp_replace | _regular | concat_regular | length_string | reverse_string | initcap_broken | initcap_orig | ltrim_broken | lpad_broken | ascii_broken | format_regular | repe
at_regular
----------------+----------+----------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+-----
-----------
 ab             | a2b      | a.2.b          | a3b           | a1\b           | a2b            | A2b          | a2b          | a...2b      | a92b         | a2b            | a222
b
(1 row)

Time: 0.420 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

You got it all wrong.
As in any other function execution, the regexp function parameters are evaluated before the execution and not during the execution.

This are the replace strings you are actually using:

```
with a as (select 'a 2 b'::text s)
select
     ''                     as empty_string
    ,'\1'                   as _regular
    ,concat('.','\1','.')   as concat_regular
    ,length('.\1')::text    as length_string
    ,reverse('\1')          as reverse_string
    ,initcap('\1')          as initcap_broken
    ,'\1'                   as initcap_orig
    ,ltrim('\1','a')        as ltrim_broken
    ,lpad('\1',5,'.')       as lpad_broken
    ,ascii('\1')::text      as ascii_broken
    ,format('\1')::text     as format_regular
    ,repeat('\1',3)         as repeat_regular
from a
```

---

```
+--------------+----------+----------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+
| empty_string | _regular | concat_regular | length_string | reverse_string | initcap_broken | initcap_orig | ltrim_broken | lpad_broken | ascii_broken | format_regular | repeat_regular |
+--------------+----------+----------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+
|              | \1       | .\1.           | 3             | 1\             | \1             | \1           | \1           | ...\1       | 92           | \1             | \1\1\1         |
+--------------+----------+----------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: yes - this is the source of the problem - using regexp meta syntax (that u can safely use in third regex_replace argument as argument to string function itself. partially it works. so I ask (because could not find anything in docs) is it meant to not be used

Comment: @VaoTsun - I don't get why do you think there is an issue. Could we discuss a specific use-case?

Comment: the guy (SO link in my question) used regexp meta syntax as argument to string functions, expecting it `\1` to be interpreted as first substitution, not as two characters "\1" - and it partially worked. So I could not understand is it meant usage or not

Comment: The guys code did exactly what it supposed to do - evaluated `' EXT ' || lpad('\1', 4, '0')` which resulted in `' EXT 00\1'`. Only then the regex function was executed.

Comment: (And what is "meta syntax"?)

Comment: I use "meta syntax" words to define special characters which help idenity difference between slashtwo and second substitution of search string. Probably my English is poor? I ask to forgive me for it.

Comment: Your english is fine (Probably better than mine :-)) but I think this expression is just increasing the misconception.

Comment: Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/42106960/6336479

Comment: And see updated answer

Comment: Yes I saw those. I also affered a simple way to achieve his goal. But apparently his question was about using lpad in regexp_replace, not hot to order by middle of the string. I found idea strange and started digging with intention to understand. So it leaded me to my question here